# Where is the table that holds the "Special Price" in Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Im trying to update the "Special_price" and "price" in bulk with mySQL an a php script, I know the table and row that contains the "price" but not the one that contains the "special_price".

I've looks though the database itself and still no luck. Any ideas? I need the table name and the field name.

Comment: look for the attribute_code in the eav_attribute table. I would bet there's a plug-in to do this, no one should be directly playing with the db in magento

Comment: :/ well ideally yes.. but im getting errors using the API. However how does the attribute id help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My membership in the Magento Question Answers Guild requires me to suggest you work on fixing your API errors instead of using plain old SQL to update the database.  As mentioned elsewhere, updating the database directly might put Magento into a state not recognized by the system, which can lead to strange, infuriating errors.

That said, the special price value will be stored with the other product attribute values in the

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

table.  This table has an `attribute_id` column, which has a foreign key relationship with the `eav_attribute` table.  Look in the `eav_attribute` table for the attribute with the code `special_price`.  That `attribute_id` and the product's `entity_id` should be enough to find the correct row in `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

Keep in mind no row will exist if a product doesn't have a `special_price` set.  Also keep in mind if a product has a `special_price` set at different scope levels that there may be more than one row.

Comment: A lot of thanks. Apreciate your answer. Mor me work fine on magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: You mean to say there is a better way of bulk updating product attributes with Magento APIs instead? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Special Price is an attribute of decimal type.
First you need to get the attribute id, by applying this sql query: 
    `SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='special_price';`

Then, you can add a special price for any product by inserting a record into `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to delete special price from a list of SKUs imported via a csv file into `temp_import_sp_price_delete`.

```
delete deci from catalog_product_entity_decimal deci, 
                 `catalog_product_entity` pr,
                 temp_import_sp_price_delete temp 
where temp.SKU= pr.SKU and pr.entity_id=deci.entity_id and deci.attribute_id=76
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question that was asked, which is about *changing* special prices, not *deleting* them.  Also, you should explain why this works and what the magic number 76 means (based on the other answers, I suspect it is only 76 in *your* database).