# Which all tables should be updated in order to edit base price of a product in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm working on the magento platform. I need to know which table contains the base price value of a product. I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504621/where-is-the-table-that-holds-the-special-price-in-magento) and got the price value column, but i need to get the product id to change the price value of the specific product. Which table contains the product id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change the base price of magento product the table catalog_product_entity_decimal value column value should be updated.
In this table entity_id denotes product id and price attribute id is 75 so

you need to run the following sql query

```
update  catalog_product_entity_decimal set value=<your price> where entity_id=<your product id> AND   attribute_id = 75
```

After changing the price you can reindex the catalog frontend will show the changed price

Comment: where to find selling price?

Comment: Theere is no attribute for final selling price. magento uses different prices likes special price, tier price, group price etc.. special price has attribtue id 76. This attribute_id 76, which has a foreign key relationship with the eav_attribute table. Look in the eav_attribute table for the attribute with the code "special_price" like wise for all other price attributes you can check the code in eav_attribute  selling price depends on above attirbutes. Normally special price takes prioriry, then tier price (if customer belongs to specified criteria)