# Magento Special-Price And discount

Tags: magento, discount

I need to setup a discount rule on magento on **all** products in the catalog, actyaly products have:

*old-price* - *special-price*

I need to setup a 20% discount on *special-price* but i can't understand how to do that.

Any help? :/

Comment: you need to use shopping cart price rule

Answer (score 0):

Is this a permanent change in price or some sort of sale you know when it will end?

If its permanent this might help

[Where is the table that holds the "Special Price" in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504621/where-is-the-table-that-holds-the-special-price-in-magento)

Just find the column with special price and multiply all values by .8 and then replace the column.